# Convert For loop to While

Tags: for-loop, while-loop, type-conversion

I want to change thise for loop into a While loop and can't figure out how

```
    scanner.close();
    for(int i=0; i<arr.length; i++){
        total = total + arr[i];
```

Answer (score 1):

Try as follow (Note: this is in JavaScript)

```
scanner.close();
var i = 0;
var total = 0;
do {
   total += arr[i];
   i++;
} while (i < arr.length);
```

Comment: for(int i=0; i<arr.length; i++){
         System.out.print("Enter Element No."+(i+1)+": ");
         arr[i] = scanner.nextDouble();
         
        }
       
        scanner.close();
        for(int i=0; i<arr.length; i++){
         total = total + arr[i];
        }
this is the full set of for loops I'mtrying to convert

Comment: @ROJO update your question with this code and please also share what you tried.

Answer (score 0):

Try this out, this is a while loop according to your for loop.

```
scanner.close();
int i = 0;
while( i < arr.length ){
  total += arr[i++];
}
```

Answer (score 0):

**a simple conversion of your code from `for` loop to `while` loop**

```
scanner.close();
int i=0; 
while(i<arr.length)
{ 
 total = total + arr[i];
 i++;
}
```